# Why is my development server in infinite reload loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, vue.js

I'm not sure this my question fits under programming, but I'll proceed either way. I'm having a rather bizarre issue wherein my development server wont stop reloading/refreshing after the first couple of (file) changes when working with create-react-app or Vue-CLI bootstrapped projects. I have to exit it every time and restart the server which is usually just a couple of minutes into working, which renders development almost impossible. An illustration of this seen in the [linked screen record](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1T8yMs9DVNMXrcAYvU9jw1mhj-CL2SYjN/view).

I'm on a Windows machine, though I'm pretty sure the problem has nothing to do with my computer, as I've worked with the same projects before. I did, however, upgrade my OS from Windows 8 to 8.1, while at the same time installing the latest version of Node.js (10.x). I used to work with version 8.x, if my memory isn't failing me, though I'm not sure if that would be the source of my worries.

Comment: No one can know without some code.

Comment: See, this happens with every single create-react-app or vue-cli project, so I'm not even sure what code I'd use for illustration for this specific issue.

Comment: Could something (maybe your IDE/Editor or some dropbox kind of thing) be saving the file multiple times? First I would try to figure out what does create-react-app use for file events on windows. Also, maybe you could create a small app (or post the steps to create one) showing the problem and share it here so other can try it on windows?

Comment: try running it the old-school way `node /path/to/index.js`. It should give an error if there is an error.

Comment: @solarc Actually, trying out another editor is a pretty good suggestion. I'll do just that and get back to you.

Comment: I have experienced these thing when i was using webstorm to edit my code by an old computer with windows 10. I opened old projects with .webstorm directory while the directory haven't been used for a long time. Then I was seeing the server reloaded and reloaded. I deleted the .webstorm directory, the problem was resolved. I don't know whether your question is the same one. Hope this helpful.

Comment: @tinwan Thanks for the suggestion. I'll look into it.